# Need help vectorizing a mathematical model written in python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I've recently written a python implementation of the Beddington DeAngelis model which is used for modeling populations of predators and preys.

My issue is that the code is extremely slow. 10.000 iterations take 230 seconds when this program has to be able to iterate 1 million times in a reasonable time frame.

I understand that I could just rewrite in C, since this is mostly just math, but I really want to learn how to properly vectorize a program like this in python.

The situation, to simplify, is that I have two arrays of shapes 200x200 and I need to iterate every element of each array while using the same index element from the other array plus some surrounding elements of the same array. So for example if I'm working on a[1][1], I will also need:

b[1][1]

a[0][1]

a[0][-1]

a[1][0]

a[-1][0]

The entire operation should be fully vectorizable, because I am changing all 200x200x2 elements in a single time step.

So how would I call this function to get these indexes?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Full code for context: (it looks intimidating, but is actually really straightforward)

```
import numpy as np
import copy
import time


def get_cell_zero_flux(m,i,j,x,y,prey):
    """
    Fetch an array element that could be outside of the border
    """
    if i >= x or i < 0 or j >= y or j < 0:
        if prey: return 0.43058 
        else: return 0.718555
    return m[i][j]


def get_laplacian(n,i,j,x,y,neighbors,h,prey):
    """
    Generate the laplacian value for the given element
    """
    total = 0
    for ng in neighbors:
        cell = get_cell_zero_flux(n,i+ng[0],j+ng[1],x,y,prey)
        total += cell
    return (total - 4*n[i][j]) / (h**2)


def next_n(n,p,nl,pl,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b):
    """
    Integrate prey population function
    """
    return n + t * (r * ( 1 - n / k ) * n
        - beta * n / ( b + n + w * p ) * p + d11 * nl + d12 * pl)


def next_p(n,p,nl,pl,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b):
    """
    Integrate predator population function
    """
    return p + t * (e * beta * n / ( b + n + w * p ) 
                * p - ni * p + d21 * nl + d22 * pl)


def generate_preys(x,y,epsilon,n_start):
    """
    Generate the initial population of preys
    """
    n = np.random.rand(x, y)
    n = np.interp(n,(n.min(),n.max()),(-epsilon/2,epsilon/2))
    n = n + n_start
    return n


def generate_predators(x,y,p_start):
    """
    Generate the initial population of predators
    """
    p = np.ones((x,y))
    p.fill(p_start)
    return p


def generate_n(n0,n,p,x,y,neighbors,h,d11,d12,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b):
    """
    Vectorized element iteration attempt for preys
    """
    i,j = np.where(n==n0) # this wouldnt work, need the current element
    n_laplacian = get_laplacian(n,i,j,x,y,neighbors,h,True)
    p_laplacian = get_laplacian(p,i,j,x,y,neighbors,h,False)
    p0 = p[i,j]
    return next_n(n0,p0,laplacian,d11,d12,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)


def generate_p(p0,p,n,x,y,neighbors,h,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b):
    """
    Vectorized element iteration attempt for predators
    """
    i,j = np.where(p==p0) # this wouldnt work, need the current element
    n_laplacian = get_laplacian(n,i,j,x,y,neighbors,h,True)
    p_laplacian = get_laplacian(p,i,j,x,y,neighbors,h,False)
    n0 = n[i,j]
    return next_p(n0,p0,n_laplacian,
                  p_laplacian,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)


def generate_system(x,y,h,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,
                    beta,k,ni,w,b,ite,n_start,p_start,epsilon):
    """
    System generation
    """

    # Initial distribution
    n = generate_preys(x,y,epsilon,n_start)
    p = generate_predators(x,y,p_start) 
    #n = n.tolist()
    #p = p.tolist()
    ps = []
    ns = []
    # neighbor list for easy laplacian neighbor fetch
    neighbors = [[-1,0],[1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]]

    t1 = time.time()

    for it in range(ite):
        # record each iteration
        old_n = copy.copy(n)
        old_p = copy.copy(p)
        ns.append(old_n)
        ps.append(old_p)

        # main array element iteration for prey and predator arrays
        for i in range(x):
            for j in range(y):
                n_laplacian = get_laplacian(old_n,i,j,x,y,neighbors,h,True)
                p_laplacian = get_laplacian(old_p,i,j,x,y,neighbors,h,False)
                n0 = old_n[i][j]
                p0 = old_p[i][j]
                n[i][j] = next_n(n0,p0,n_laplacian,p_laplacian,
                             d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)
                p[i][j] = next_p(n0,p0,n_laplacian,p_laplacian,
                             d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)

        """    
        n = generate_n(old_n,old_n,old_p,x,y,neighbors,
                    h,d11,d12,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)
        p = generate_p(old_p,old_p,old_n,x,y,neighbors,
                    h,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)
        """

    t2 = time.time()
    print(t2-t1)
    return ns,ps


ns,ps = generate_system(x=50,y=50,h=0.25,d11=0.01,d12=0.0115,d21=0.01,d22=1,
                        t=0.01,r=0.5,e=1,beta=0.6,k=2.6,ni=0.25,w=0.4,b=0.3154,
                        ite=10,n_start=0.43058,p_start=0.718555,epsilon=0.001)
```

Expected output is calculating 1 million iterations in a few minutes on a 200x200 grid, but taking 230 seconds just for 10.000 in a 40x40 grid

**EDIT**

I managed to vectorize the whole program. Performance boost was 400x fold. WOW

Here is the new code:

```
import numpy as np
import copy
import time

def next_n(n,p,nl,pl,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b):
    """
    Integrate prey population function
    """
    return n + t * (r * ( 1 - n / k ) * n
        - beta * n / ( b + n + w * p ) * p + d11 * nl + d12 * pl)


def next_p(n,p,nl,pl,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b):
    """
    Integrate predator population function
    """
    return p + t * (e * beta * n / ( b + n + w * p ) 
                * p - ni * p + d21 * nl + d22 * pl)


def generate_preys(x,y,epsilon,n_start):
    """
    Generate the initial population of preys
    """
    n = np.random.rand(x, y)
    n = np.interp(n,(n.min(),n.max()),(-epsilon/2,epsilon/2))
    n = n + n_start
    n[0,:] = n_start
    n[-1:,:] = n_start
    n[:,0] = n_start
    n[:,-1:] = n_start
    return n


def generate_predators(x,y,p_start):
    """
    Generate the initial population of predators
    """
    p = np.ones((x,y))
    p.fill(p_start)
    return p


def get_laps(a,x,y,h):

    center = a[1:-1,1:-1]
    left = a[1:-1,0:-2]
    right = a[1:-1,2:]
    top = a[0:-2,1:-1]
    bottom = a[2:,1:-1]
    return (left+right+top+bottom - 4*center) / (h**2)

def generate_system(x,y,h,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,
                    beta,k,ni,w,b,ite,n_start,p_start,epsilon):
    """
    System generation
    """

    # Initial distribution
    n = generate_preys(x+2,y+2,epsilon,n_start)
    p = generate_predators(x+2,y+2,p_start) 
    ps = []
    ns = []
    t1 = time.time()

    for it in range(ite):
        if it % 10000 == 0:
            print(f"iterations passed: {it}")
            ns.append(copy.copy(n))
            ps.append(copy.copy(p)) 
        # record each iteration

        nl = get_laps(n,x,y,h)
        pl = get_laps(p,x,y,h)
        nc = n[1:-1,1:-1]
        pc = p[1:-1,1:-1]
        n[1:-1,1:-1] = next_n(nc,pc,nl,pl,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)
        p[1:-1,1:-1] = next_p(nc,pc,nl,pl,d11,d12,d21,d22,t,r,e,beta,k,ni,w,b)

    t2 = time.time()
    print(f"Time taken: {t2-t1}")
    return ns,ps


ns,ps = generate_system(x=200,y=200,h=0.25,d11=0.01,d12=0.0115,d21=0.01,d22=1,
                        t=0.01,r=0.5,e=1,beta=0.6,k=2.6,ni=0.25,w=0.4,b=0.3154,
                        ite=100,n_start=0.43058,p_start=0.718555,epsilon=0.001)
```

Comment: There is _way_ too much code here to expect us to work through. Rather than drop the entire project into a question, you'd be better focusing on a single theme to ask about/research that you might apply to several of these operations (preempting an approach, _don't_ use `np.vectorize` to apply a function to an array, it's just a misnomer for a `for` loop)

Comment: A skim of the code looks relatively sound, though you pass lots of arguments to your functions. But laying out code this way does no lend itself to vectorization either because, if you have to keep calling Python functions, you're always going to be stuck in Python time. You may have to come up with a radically different data structure to support this for speed, which won't be as clear as general Python(not saying this is a bad thing, but array programming is sometimes more abstract than what you've written).

Comment: @roganjosh I see. I updated the post a bit to reflect on the core problem without needing the code. I do think it could 'kinda' get vectorized, given that I'm transforming all the elements in the same time step. There dont exist any dependancies. I could work on this as a 3D array, but im not sure how numpy would even talk with that. All the examples ive seen use 2d arrays when iterating.

Comment: It's not a point of dependencies. If you have to call a python function on an array --> you're basically barred from vectorization

Comment: "I could work on this as a 3D array, but im not sure how numpy would even talk with that. All the examples ive seen use 2d arrays when iterating." well if they were explicitly iterating in a python `for` loop then they weren't vectorized in that respect

Comment: Ohhh, now I see. So essentially, rather than having that function take 1 element at a time, I should rewrite to pass n and p as the entire arrays. I'll give it a go, looks like a minor change actually.

Comment: Yes, the point is to apply a single operation to the entire array in one call. Hopefully it's as easy as you envisage, good luck :)

Comment: @roganjosh I did it! Changed everything to matrix additions and got a 400x peformance boost!!! I updated the question with the update. I'm sure I could get even more if I used a smarter way of calculating the laplacians. Pretty sure it's matrix multiplication for the get_laps function? Regardless, thank you very much for the advice!